# Tool to fix rapid-fire dropouts?

Tags: audio, software, fix

I recorded a phone call and the cell service was pretty shoddy. Here's [an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wet8oc1o5fowhto/Stuttering%20example.mp3?dl=0). Good briefly, then high-speed dropouts, then good again.

In the below image, you can see the dropouts to the right of the red line.

Is there anyway to fill in those very thin and frequent dropouts? It seems like it *should* be reasonably, programmatically, simple to do it. Just fill in those blanks, gradually "morphing" it from the start sound to the end sound.

Any ideas or advice would be appreciated. I've encountered this problem consistently and would love to be able to deal with it.[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly what components, but RX should be your starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I use Reaper (primarily) and Audacity (secondarily) on Windows. I'm not sure what RX (or for that matter, "components") refer to.

Comment: Apologies - Izotope RX

Comment: @Mark Thanks. Will look into it.

Comment: Wrote their customer support. Their software doesn’t address this particular issue, It should! Seems very pattern-like. Ah well.